# How to integrate Java Web Start to browser?

Tags: java

I have sun-java6-plugin installed on my 10.10 AMD64, and I tested on the Java website that it works with applets.

However it doesn't work with web start - I have to download the jnlp file and double click to open.

Is there a way to integrate web start to my browsers?

Comment: It's a protocol handler thing.  It works for me, but the jnlp handler might be disabled as a security risk(it can be).

Comment: what broswer might be helpful

Comment: I have both Firefox and Chrome installed. Both don't work for jnlp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox go,

```
Edit -> Prefferences -> Applications -> JNLP File 
Choose SunJDK Java 6 Web Start
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this and I resolved it by intalling icedtea-6-plugin or icedtea-7-plugin. It depends on the case.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate web start to my browsers follow the steps.

If you just run the applet code inside html tags it doesn't work. Run them inside script(javascript) tags.

1. get the jars and class out of jnlp file and put them into applet code.
2. then make that applet runs as java script from your html code.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome running on top of Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic:

1. Open a terminal window (ctrl+alt+t)
2. Type the following command:

sudo apt-get install icedtea-8-plugin

3. Instead of double-clicking over the .jnlp file icon, try to run it also from a terminal by executing a command-line equivalent to the following, when you'll replace the URL below by the one that links to your .jnlp file:

javaws http://some.adress.com/webapp/myapp.jnlp

Tips:
a) In step 3, you may be notified about the availability of a newer version. I strongly recommend that you try, at first, with the current java version already available at your machine before updating it to any newer ones. 
b) It's very likely that this same approach will be effective for other Ubuntu versions.